# Why won't DIV center?

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV that contains two elements: a video and an image. I would like these to remain centered horizontally; however, they're slightly off center toward the right. Can anyone spot my error?

**HTML:**

```
<center>

  <div id="videoWrapper">
    <canvas height="46%" width="46%"></canvas>
    <video id="video1" preload="metadata" controls>
      <source src="../Images/J's Garden FINAL MOVIE.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video><img src="../Images/videonav1.png" id="test" width="25%"   height="46%">
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#videoWrapper{
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video{
  height: 46%   !important;
}
#test{
  height: 46%;
}
```

Comment: use div {border:1px solid black;} to help debug.

Comment: Do you want a [result like this](http://jsfiddle.net/2vLtcsnu/)?

Comment: Are you actually using the HTML center tag, or was that just a test? The center tag is depreciated in HTML5 and should be replaced with CSS.

Comment: Is the canvas element the problem? Here's a JSFiddle that shows why the other two elements are slightly to the right of the center: http://jsfiddle.net/2vLtcsnu/1/

Answer (score 3):

As was already said, the center tag is deprecated and should not be used. I've reorganized your CSS to achieve the effect you're looking for. Basically the `canvas` tag was sitting beside the video tag, pushing it to the side. I find that it helps when troubleshooting to apply arbitrary background colors to each element to see how they interact with each other.

In this example I've used `text-align: center` to center the items

```css
#videoWrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
#videoWrapper * {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
#video1,
#test {
    height: 46%;
}
```

```html
<div id="videoWrapper">
    <canvas height="46%" width="46%"></canvas>
    <video id="video1" preload="metadata" controls>
        <source src="../Images/J's Garden FINAL MOVIE.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <img src="../Images/videonav1.png" id="test" width="25%" height="46%">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i believe by default image tag is inline, so you make it center by text-align:center, you cal also try the textalign:center on the videowrapper div